Дизайнер для Winforms
Есть ли какой то визуальный дизайнер форм для Visual Studio Code?
Есть проект на C# доставшийся по наследству. Есть только VSCode. Не нашел чем можно работать с визуальными формами в этой среде.

Такого дизайнера нет. Установите VS 2022, не вижу проблемы

была б возможность - поставил бы...

Если .NET свежий, есть Hot Reload, то есть UI можно дебажить прямо в запущенном приложении.

в первую очередь нужно его (UI) увидеть... :-)

Собрать и запустить приложение с включенным отладчиком?

не собирается... в том то и проблема! задача переложить все это удовольствие на другую платформу - Qt

ну тогда надо вопрос про реальную проблему задавать, а не про дизайнер
